# excel 2010 Paste Link radio button disabled with chart object

Tags: excel, charts

I've created a chart in a workbook. I want to copy and paste that chart into another workbook in such a way so that when I update the original data it automatically updates both charts.
Between Excel and Word there are no problems: I can paste the chart as link (see below):

[image: Word paste Link]

but in Excel the same option seems to be disabled:

[image: Excel Paste Link]

Any idea to solve my problem? The chart copied in the destination only updates if the original file is open, and the data changed!

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've not done this much, but when I have I generally just paste (i.e. Ctrl+C). The chart series should be automatically updated to refer to the source workbook, the relevant worksheet within that workbook, and keep the cell ranges the same.

So my thought would be that the option isn't disabled, it's just implicitly built in to the normal paste. Which would make sense; The use-case for keeping the same source range of cells, but on the new worksheet being pasted to (even inside the same workbook, let alone in a different workbook) is not exactly one that seems crazy useful.